# Slider de notícias bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Boas, estou com um problema num slider.

Tenho um slider com 3 caixas de notícias e quero rodar de 3 em 3 caixas, até aqui tudo bem, já está a funcionar, mas o problema e quando passo para dispositivo móvel o conteudo e alterado para bloco mas em vez de me aumentar a caixa de fundo fica por cima de todo o conteudo a baixo

### NOTÍCIAS

```
     <div class="carousel slide" id="noticias">
            <div class="carousel-inner conteudo">
              <div class="item active" id="noticias">





                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_01.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                    <div class="service-item">                                                      
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_02.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">                      
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_03.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>








        </div>




        <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_01.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                    <div class="service-item">                                                      
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_02.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="service-item">                      
                        <div class="service-desc">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
                            <p><img src="img/news/teste_03.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="control-box">                            
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#noticias" class="carousel-controla left">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#noticias" class="carousel-controla right">›</a>
    </div><!-- /.control-box -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: screenshot]

o objetivo era ter algo deste genero:

[image: Imagem de como queria que ficasse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar a classe .clearfix no slider, dê uma olhada na documentação http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix

Answer (score 3):

A classe `col-md-4` só é aplicada se a tela tiver pelo menos 970px de largura.

Para funcionar em dispositivos móveis adicione outras classes de acordo com o tamanho da tela conforme [descrito na documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) em:

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
```

sugiro adicionar a classes `col-xs-4` ou `col-sm-4`.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua colaboração, mas eu quero que ele fique em coluna como está, mas também queria que o fundo preto acompanha-se as noticias em toda a altura das notícias